# Is there a list of motifs and labels of this motifs?

Tags: motif

I'm trying to make a list of the short motifs e.g. in Baroque, which are the elements in the music by Bach, Vivaldi, Händel et all.

I have found some lists  of figures, ornaments, decorations in the common practice period (which also may fit in 12 tone music).

Now I am trying to find names for these short motifs like c,d,e,c and their variation (all kind of inversions) as:  c,b,a,c (horizontally mirroring or c,e,d,c (crab) and c,a,b,c. (But I don't search for this terms of transforming! What I'm looking for are just a names of e.g. this figure: passing tone 1-3 and back.

I'm sure I have found once a list  of such motifs (and their labeling. (Similar to the names of the *Neumes* in Greorian chant notation because I consider them as a development of those neumen motifs.)

What I could name is: triads (e.g. Alberti bass) and "Läufer" (scale),
I've once also read the name "Ruggiero" for the Bass motif solatiso doremido, that is also used in the 5th sequences progressions - but I'm not sure about this and I can't find the source again.

I hope your answers can help me

- with links or already existing lists
- with graphic (de)signs to recognize or systematize them,
- e.g. typical songs like we use to learn the intervals - e.g: 
  "There's a place for us" -> minor 7th, "Maria" -> augmented 4th (West Side Story)  This can be folk songs, baby songs, pop songs, classical motifs.

as an example the sequenced motif above mi,fa,so,mi - re,mi,fa,re - do-re-mi-do I'd name "the piggies motif"

Answer (score 3):

I found this dissertation (open access) a few years ago, and I have returned to it many times for all the great ideas it contains:

*Callahan (2010) [Techniques of Keyboard Improvisation in the German Baroque and
Their Implications for Today’s Pedagogy](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/institutionalPublicationPublicView.action?institutionalItemId=13844)*

Some screen shots with named figures:

P. 110

[image]

P. 132

[image]

P. 133

[image]

P. 261

[image]

You will notice Callahan quotes a lot from Michael Wiedeburg an 18th century German musician. The source of that stuff is *[Der sich selbst informirende Clavierspieler](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Wiedeburg,_Michael_Johann_Friedrich)*. Unfortunately, for me, it's in German and I can't read the text. But that shouldn't be a problem for you!

If you were wondering about the English names of these kinds of figures, I don't think there are standard names. But in an academic setting people often use the German terms. Like *ursatz* from Schenker. An English speaker would probably just call a *schneller* a schneller.

Sort of related are some *phrase length* terms from Joseph Riepel: Zweyer, Dreyer, and Vierer... 
 "two-measure unit," "three-measure unit," and "four-measure unit." Found in translation from German in: Strunk, [Source Readings in Music History](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZtCYwFm2mTwC&pg=PA751).

Comment: +1) Very useful, something like this I’m looking for. I’m expecting more creativity and fantasy  of other members. May be the other contributions are more individual, but I think if we all work together we could build a catalogue of motifs like grammatical modules in language.

Comment: Great dissertation! He also gave a great presentation on this, with live improvisation, shortly thereafter.

Comment: Hi Richard, where was that presentation given?

Comment: It was at the Society for Music Theory's 2010 annual meeting in Indianapolis.